# Spatial search performance on a collection of Points in a PostGis database

Tags: buffer, spatial-index, postgis-1.5, search

Let's assume you have a huge PostGis spatial table (using Postgresql 9.2, postgis 1.5) :

> BIGTABLE ( p Point, someData varchar )

which contains millions of records. 
Each record has been created with a Point and each point has an associated varchar data (let's call it the useful information).

Now, let's say there is another spatial table from which you also can get a Point field :

> SOMESEARCHPOINTS ( ... , p Point , ...)

For a given set of points from the SOMESEARCHPOINTS table (which are retrieved from a subquery on this table), I want to find the corresponding "someData" varchar using a JOIN.

```
SELECT * FROM SOMESEARCHPOINTS sp
LEFT JOIN BIGTABLE b ON ( XXXXXXXXXXX )
```

The XXXXXXXXXXX being the join condition.

The question is : without modifying the current schema (meaning without changing the geometry type), is it possible to have an efficient XXXXXXXXXXX join condtion ? If not, what is the proper way to do that ?

Comment: This is what spatial indexes are designed to do, efficiently -- essentially build a sequence of successively smaller boxes to efficiently search in 2d. There is no substitute for testing, but 10 million is well within Postgres/Postgis's capabilities and if you start buffering things, you are adding complexity for no extra performance gain.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the performance issues are then more related to the query itself then (basically, the join is done on a too great number of rows).

Comment: Sorry, I am half asleep, st_contains with a point against a point will not be efficient. Your search geometry should be a buffered point.

Comment: Well, I was wondering how a point could have a Bounding Box.....I mean, spatial search is efficient thanks to bounding boxes, isn't it ?

Comment: I've done further testing and I think creating a buffer at query time is not a good idea. I will edit my question, since I can't put block quote in a comment.

Comment: A table that large will be subject to spatial fragmentation performance issues.  You should make sure the table order is clustered, such that drawing all features fills in bands from left/right to top/bottom or top/bottom to left/right. The performance difference, vice random distribution,  could be measured in minutes.

Comment: @Vince. Really. I have tables of 500 million geometries that return everything inside a search polygon in milliseconds, just using a Gist index.

Comment: Creating lots of buffers is a bad idea at query time. I'm still not entirely clear what you are trying to do: can't you just buffer a single search polygon and find all points inside it -- which will be efficient as it will use the index and only involve buffering one object?

Comment: @JohnBarça The goal is to find for each 500 points (or more) from the SEARCHPOINT table the corresponding (optional, hence the left join) someData varchar contained in the BIGTABLE.
Do you mean I need to create a polygon from the 500 input points ? How would you do that with a LEFT JOIN ?
I don't know if that's clear enough ;)
A solution would be to store in the BIGTABLE a buffered object around each point. (it would be less efficient in storage space, but that is not an issue).

Comment: @JohnBarça Actually, the BIGTABLE is some kind of a very big cache (key => value). The important thing is the "someData" varchar column which I need to associate with each input points from the SEARCHTABLE.

Comment: That's a different question then :D. Are you using hstore?

Comment: No. Don't even know about it ;) I'm going to read the doc right now ;)
Are you sure it's relevant ? When I say that the BIGTABLE is a cache of key => value, I meant that the  key is the Geometry and the value is the someData varchar data... and I want to be able to query in this cache to retrieve the data.

Comment: Using functions like st_contains, st_buffer and st_distance for *searching* is nearly always the wrong way to go. You should investigate and use the **st_dwithin** function. There are many questions or answers involving st_dwithin on this site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting points within a range from a postgres database?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42920/getting-points-within-a-range-from-a-postgres-database)

Comment: @martinf Thanks. I've got the same performance issue using st_dwithin... I guess it's because the geometries involved here are just "Points".
The only solution might be to store buffer in the database and I just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @martinf BTW, I don't think this is a duplicate since the link you mention is not about searching a singular point among a huge collection of singular points.

Comment: Can you rewrite the entire question using only st_dwithin or without naming any function (just defining the problem)? I suspect you'll find a solution that way.

Comment: @martinf I've just edited my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the points that you want to join is really identical (you wrote one table is a subset of the other) you should be able to just join on intersecting bboxes.

If you have a working spatial index that will be very fast. Just use the && operator between the points.

If the points is not identical you can expand one of the bboxes. That is what st_dwithin does before rechecking by calculating the exact distances. But if approx distance is enough to find the right point comparing bboxes is enough.

Comment: The points are not identical (well, they might be, but it would just be a coincidence)
`If the points is not identical you can expand one of the bboxes.`
How can a point have a bounding box ? 

I have tried with st_dwithin, and it is very slow.

Comment: Well, It can. It could be just that the box have all corners in the point. In PostGIS bboxes is represented with Int32 coordinates and the point with Int64 coordinates. So the box actually has a small area. it doesn't matter if the index gives a few false positive intersections since the result is rechecked.

Comment: about "very slow" I have to ask if you really have a functional spatial index. do explain tell you that you have an index scan? and is "very slow" compared to something else or just takes to long to run your query? the slow part of st_dwithin is the recheck where all results from the index scan is checked by real distance calculations. if you just expand bboxes and use the && operator it will be very fast. Look at the sql-definition of st_dwithin how it is done. there is a special trick to keep the index working by expanding one of the two comparing points and then the other.

Comment: thanks for the explanation about boxes.
Well, it is slow compared to just using ST_Contains between the points (slow meaning I have to interrupt the query).... but using st_contains takes about 1.5 seconds for searching 500 points among 3M points....I thought it could have been faster....but after reading your explanation, there might be no other way....

Comment: Using && is as fast as using st_contains...and Explain analyze reports that it takes 1108.000 ms to do the index scan on the BIGTABLE. (83% of the total query time).